# Flutter: setState does not update inner widget

Tags: flutter, setstate, statefulwidget

I have a song playlist screen that includes a list of songs and a navbar for audio play/pause. I set the initial value of the song field as the first element of the songs list, however, when I update the selected song with `setState()`, the navbar does not update its song.

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BodyState createState() => BodyState();
}

class BodyState extends State<Body> {
  Music selectedSong = songs[0];
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
       ...
       Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          itemCount: songs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => songCard(songs[i])
       ...
       MusicBar(music: selectedSong)
```

For **songCard()** function:

```
 Widget songCard(Music item) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () => {
        setState(() {
          selectedSong = item;
        })
      },
     ...
```

When I debug the code, `selectedSong` field is updated as expected, however `music` field inside `MusicBar` is not updated.

For MusicBar class:

```
class MusicBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Music music;
  const MusicBar({Key key, this.music}) : super(key: key);
  MusicBarState createState() => MusicBarState(music: music);
}

class MusicBarState extends State<MusicBar> {

  final Music music;
  MusicBarState({this.music});

  AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // duration = music.duration;
    player.onDurationChanged.listen((updatedDuration) {
      setState(() {
        duration = updatedDuration;
      });
    });

    player.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((updatedPosition) {
        setState(() {
          position = updatedPosition;
        });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
    player.stop();
    player.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Container(
      ...
```

What did I do wrong so that the `MusicBar` widget is not updating?
If needed, songs list is defined outside `Body` class, and I am using `audioplayers` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MusicBarState you can access to music field on Music using `widget`. You can refactor you State to:

```dart
class MusicBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Music music;
  const MusicBar({Key key, this.music}) : super(key: key);
  MusicBarState createState() => MusicBarState(); // Empty constructor
}

class MusicBarState extends State<MusicBar> {
  // Remove this
  // final Music music;
  // MusicBarState({this.music});

 someMethod() {
   // You can access to music using widget:
   print(widget.music);
 }
 // ...
}
```

Test and check if now works

Comment: how does this differ? I want to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: The build method render all `widgets` after setState is called. If you pass a music reference to StatefulWidget and then to State, only reference it's passed and State cannot view changes in your music reference in the widget. The createState method only calls when the widget has a create new state and not when his parents are updated. If you use `widget`, all times a MusicBar rebuilding you can make sure that you are always taking the new references that are passed to the widget and not to the state

Comment: Oh thanks! But how can I detect if widget.music changed? Because I need to stop playing and reset the slider so that I can play the new song. Is there any function that I can listen StatefulWidget changes in State?

Comment: You can try to implement some pattern like `Observer` in your` Music` model. You could also use a state manager (like Provider, Bloc, etc) to manipulate the state of the current music if you are going to use it in different parts or globally.

Comment: You can also just override the didChangeDependecies method of your navbar state.

Comment: @GaspardMerten yeah that worked as well, thanks!